# ASP.NET Core Web Api automatic help pages

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0, asp.net-core-webapi

In previous versions of ASP.NET, when I created Web Api 2, visual studio automatically wired up automatic generation of documentation for the API.

It's also explained here:
http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/creating-api-help-pages

I'm writing a new project and I've decided to do it with ASP.NET Core, but I don't see anything similar to what existed in the previous versions that generates the documentation from the API (I'm also guessing that's its a bit different since all controllers now inherit from the same `Controller` class).

But, is there some way to have help files generated for ASP.NET Core APIs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The functionality you want is at https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle

The following link provides an example of how to configure and use the well-designed utility
https://damienbod.com/2015/12/13/asp-net-5-mvc-6-api-documentation-using-swagger/

Answer (score 1):

John Davidson made a good post showing how to generate Swagger documentation - that is useful and great.

But if you want to stick to **ASP.Net MVC 5 - Api Explorer documentation,** you should have a look to that excellent blog post :

https://andrewlock.net/introduction-to-the-apiexplorer-in-asp-net-core/